# Why doesn't my function show and hide elements as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, conditional-statements

Firstly - I'm a bit green with JS so please go easy!
I'm trying to show / hide 2 different divs based on selection of a country. 
Basically if a user select UK it shows a UK address div, and if they select any other country, an international div appears.

Ultimately, I only want 1 div to appear at a time, so need them to toggle on and off based on selection.

I have used an existing solution to get to the stage I'm at:

```html
<div>
  <label>Country:</label>
  <select name="country" id="country" class="fullselect" onclick="craateUserJsObject.ShowPrivileges();">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom UK">United Kingdom UK</option>
    <option value="Vietnam VN">Vietnam VN</option>
    <option value="Vanuatu VU">Vanuatu VU</option>
    <option value="Wallis And Futuna Islands WF">Wallis And Futuna Islands WF</option>
    <option value="Western Samoa WS">Western Samoa WS</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="lookupbox" style=" display: block;">UK Lookup Box</div>
<div class="manualbox" style=" display: none;">International Input Box</div>
```

```js
var Privileges = jQuery('#country');
var select = this.value;

Privileges.change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'United Kingdom UK') {
    $('.lookupbox').show();
    $('.manualbox').hide()
  } else 
    $('.manualbox').show();

  $('.lookupbox').hide();
});
```

It works in that it hides the international div when UK is selected, but it doesn't show the UK div!

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RWUdb/1340/)

I assume that there's something incredibly basic that I'm missing, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your problem is that on your else conditional is ending at $('.manualbox').show(); The $('.lookupbox').hide();  is executing everytime. The reason for that is that you do not have { } for your else conditional. Just add and it will work. Since you do not have {} it will end on your first ;

Comment: WOW, so simple and so quick! Thank you very much it works perfectly :)

Comment: Just FYI, if you use an IDE which has formatting features, then you can easily spot errors like this. I've updated the code in the question so that the formatting makes it easier to spot the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem exists with your `else`:

```
if ($(this).val() == 'United Kingdom UK') {
    $('.lookupbox').show();
    $('.manualbox').hide()
}
else $('.manualbox').show();
    $('.lookupbox').hide();
```

Since you are not enclosing both statements, only the first is affected by the `if / else` while the second executes every time.

```
if ($(this).val() == 'United Kingdom UK') {
    $('.lookupbox').show();
    $('.manualbox').hide()
} else {
    $('.manualbox').show();
    $('.lookupbox').hide(); 
}
```

Adding curly braces will resolve your issue.